# MySQL - How to transfer values from one table to another depending on criteria

Tags: mysql

I would like to insert into table `b` values from table `a` based on a conditions that compare `a` to `b`.

For example, let `a` be this `student` table:

```
╔═════╦═══════╦══════╗
║ id* ║ name  ║ age  ║
╠═════╬═══════╬══════╣
║  1  ║ John  ║  12  ║
║  2  ║ Sam   ║  14  ║
╚═════╩═══════╩══════╝
```

And let `b` be a `grade` table:

```
╔═════╦═══════╗
║ id  ║ name  ║
╠═════╬═══════╣
║  ?  ║ John  ║
║  ?  ║ Sam   ║
╚═════╩═══════╝
```

I think the syntax might look like this:

```
INSERT INTO grade.id
  SELECT id FROM student
  WHERE grade.name = student.name;
```

The output table should be:

```
╔═════╦═══════╗
║ id  ║ name  ║
╠═════╬═══════╣
║  1  ║ John  ║
║  2  ║ Sam   ║
╚═════╩═══════╝
```

I'm getting an error that `grade.id` is not a table, which makes sense. But I'm not sure how to do what I would like.

Sorry for the contrived example. The real tables are a lot more complex. Basically, I want to copy certain values from one table to another, provided certain criteria match.

Comment: Time to learn about `JOIN`.

Comment: I've used `JOIN` in simple cases, but I'm not sure how to use it in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring for now the fact that you are probably breaking the normalisation of the database, you've nearly got the answer (which you can also [find in the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html))

```
INSERT INTO grade (id,name)
SELECT id,name FROM student
;
```

Insert adds rows it doesn't change them. For that you need an update or replace.

```
Update grade
Set id=( select id from student
      WHERE grade.name = student.name);
```

BTW this will break if student.name is not unique.

Answer (score 1):

If you already have a grade table, and you just need to update the ID column you could use this:

```
UPDATE
  grade INNER JOIN student
  ON grade.name = student.name
SET
  grade.id = student.id
```